# c__app.exe has stopped working?

Tags: c++

I've a simple application written in `c++`(just learning) but my application does not run properly. Here's my code:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include "Player.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    Player p1("Anish");
    Player p2("ASK");
    cout << "Game starts." << endl;
    cout << p1.getPlayerName() << " has " << p1.getHitPoint() << " hitpoints." << endl;
    cout << p2.getPlayerName() << " has " << p2.getHitPoint() << " hitpoints." << endl;
    p1.hit(&p2);

   // cout << p2.getHitPoint();
    cout << p1.getPlayerName() << " hits " << p2.getPlayerName() << endl;
    cout << p1.getPlayerName() << " has " << p1.getHitPoint() << " hitpoints." << endl;
    cout << p2.getPlayerName() << " has " << p2.getHitPoint() << " hitpoints." << endl;
    p1.heal(&p2);
    cout << p1.getPlayerName() << " heals " << p2.getPlayerName() << endl;
    cout << p1.getPlayerName() << " has " << p1.getHitPoint() << " hitpoints." << endl;
    cout << p2.getPlayerName() << " has " << p2.getHitPoint() << " hitpoints." << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Player.cpp**

```
#include "Player.h"

Player::Player(string name) {
    playerName=name;
    setHitPoint(100);
}

void Player::setHitPoint(int points){
    hitPoint=points;
}

Player Player::hit(Player* p){
    Player player=*p;
    int point=player.getHitPoint()-10;
    player.setHitPoint(point);
}

Player Player::heal(Player* p){
    Player player=*p;
    player.setHitPoint(player.getHitPoint()+5);
}
```

**Player.h**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

#ifndef PLAYER_H
#define PLAYER_H

class Player {
public:
    Player(string);
    Player hit(Player*);
    Player heal(Player*);
    void setHitPoint(int);
    int getHitPoint() {return hitPoint;};
    string getPlayerName() {return playerName;};
private:
    string playerName;
    int hitPoint;
};

#endif  /* PLAYER_H */
```

These code give the following output:
**Build**

```
Game starts.
Anish has 100 hitpoints.
ASK has 100 hitpoints.

RUN FAILED (exit value -1,073,741,819, total time: 2s)
```

**And stops working.**
Can anyone give an idea about the problem? I don't get any errors too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start with fixing these:

```
Player Player::hit(Player* p){
    Player player=*p;
    int point=player.getHitPoint()-10;
    player.setHitPoint(point);
}

Player Player::heal(Player* p){
    Player player=*p;
    player.setHitPoint(player.getHitPoint()+5);
}
```

You're actually copying the player that was passed in.  C++ is not like Java where everything is an object/pointer/reference.  C++ likes to make copies of things.  "Player player=*p" says "make a copy of what p is pointing to and put it into player."

Then, your function says it is going to return a Player but it returns nothing.  The compiler is core dumping on that because it tries to destroy something that doesn't exist. (I'm a bit surprised your compiler isn't giving you an error.)

Try these:

```
void Player::hit(Player* p){
    int point=p->getHitPoint()-10;
    p->setHitPoint(point);
}

void Player::heal(Player* p){
    p->setHitPoint(p->getHitPoint()+5);
}
```